# After NHibernate Commit Transaction received 'The COMMIT TRANSACTION request has no corresponding BEGIN TRANSACTION. '

Tags: nhibernate, transactionscope

I use Transaction scope for distributed transactions and NHibernate inner transactions.
After all operations I check if `Transaction.Current` is not aborted and try to commit NHibernate transaction.

Sometimes I receive this error:

> The COMMIT TRANSACTION request has no corresponding BEGIN TRANSACTION.
>   The transaction active in this session has been committed or aborted
>   by another session.

With the following stacktrace:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception,
>   Boolean breakConnection) в
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException
>   exception, Boolean breakConnection) в
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj) в System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior
>   runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream,
>   BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj) в
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TdsExecuteTransactionManagerRequest(Byte[]
>   buffer, TransactionManagerRequestType request, String transactionName,
>   TransactionManagerIsolationLevel isoLevel, Int32 timeout,
>   SqlInternalTransaction transaction, TdsParserStateObject stateObj,
>   Boolean isDelegateControlRequest) в
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.ExecuteTransactionYukon(TransactionRequest
>   transactionRequest, String transactionName, IsolationLevel iso,
>   SqlInternalTransaction internalTransaction, Boolean
>   isDelegateControlRequest) в
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.ExecuteTransaction(TransactionRequest
>   transactionRequest, String name, IsolationLevel iso,
>   SqlInternalTransaction internalTransaction, Boolean
>   isDelegateControlRequest) в
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalTransaction.Commit() в
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlTransaction.Commit() в
>   NHibernate.Transaction.AdoTransaction.Commit().

The main problem that this error is occasional. What could be the reason for this?

Answer (score 0):

looks like you are not opening your sesions through a centralized code but closing the session transaction every time, else i dont see a reason for this happening..

make sure you have the same code path that is being used at the location where this error is thrown.. probably looking at the stack trace.